# Android webview not connecting to local raspberry pi server

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

I'm trying to create an app that uses `Webview` to connect to a raspberry pi web server I've created. It contains basically a few buttons that act as a garage door opener. For some reason, when I launch the app, it just displays a blank screen; but if I put in another website like Google in myWebView.loadUrl() , it loads just fine. I've added the

```
'<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />'
```

inside the manifest

Here's the  Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.24:8000/garage.html");
  }
}
```

Here is the xml in content_main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
  tools:context="com.example.michael.garageopener.MainActivity"
  tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to clarify a bit about what you're expecting to see instead of a blank screen :)

Comment: It's not clear what the content of your HTML file is or if your Web server is running on the Pi

Comment: You should really set/override callbacks from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.htm to see what is going on. Also note that you need to be connected to the same wifi to where the server is if its local UNLESS it is exposed to the internet.

Comment: @JoeTraex That local IP address wouldn't work over the Internet

Comment: try to access the url in your web browser and see if you can access it

Comment: @cricket_007 Please read my comment again.. I said 'Also note that you need to be connected to the same wifi to where the server is if its local UNLESS it is exposed to the internet.'

Comment: Most probably you are doing it on LAN ,so did you tested your webpage in your desktop browser .